# I want to run a function only one time while my condition is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

I have an arry of balls, and I want to add balls to that array when the user clicks space. The problem is that when space button is clicked the conditions stays true 1 to 2 seconds and it creates haundreds of balls instade of only one ball. How can I create only one ball even if the condition is true all the time.

```js
let balls = [
        {
          x: totalWidth / 2,
          y: totalHeight / 2,
          speed: 8,
          size: 20,
          color: 'red',
          leader: true,
        },
      ];
      
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 32) {
            let newSize = (balls[0].size/2);

            let newBall = {
              x: balls[0].x +100,
              y: balls[0].y +100,
              speed: 0,
              size: newSize,
            }

            balls.push(newBall);
            console.log(balls);

            balls.forEach(ball => {
              ball.size = newSize;
            })
          }
        });
```

Comment: look into debounce

Answer (score 0):

use `removeEventListner`

```js
const totalHeight = 10;
const totalWidth = 10;
let balls = [
        {
          x: totalWidth / 2,
          y: totalHeight / 2,
          speed: 8,
          size: 20,
          color: 'red',
          leader: true,
        },
      ];
      
const keydownFunction = e => {
    if(e.keyCode == 32) {
      let newSize = (balls[0].size/2);

      let newBall = {
        x: balls[0].x +100,
        y: balls[0].y +100,
        speed: 0,
        size: newSize,
      }

      balls.push(newBall);
      console.log(balls);

      balls.forEach(ball => {
        ball.size = newSize;
      })
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', keydownFunction);
    }
}
      
window.addEventListener('keydown', keydownFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `keydown` event fired multiple times util user release the key. You can check [`e.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat) at first in your event handler.

Or, if you want the event handler only been invoked once. You can add [`{ once: boolean }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters) parameter for `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution could be to modify your if-statment here:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 32) {
```

to

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 32 && !e.repeat) {
```

The `repeat` param indicates that certain key was held and in your case we want to perform something only when there was no repeat i.e. `e.repeat == false` or in short form `!e.repeat`

Comment: It didn't really work, the browser detectes a repeatition after enough time to log 40 times to the console